# Jquery double click issue after selecting text in IE

Tags: jquery, double-click, mousedown

For IE double click on text selection was not working for me hence i have created the separate event for selecting the text on double click.

for Eg.

```
   var editor = $("#TargetContent");

   editor.dblclick(function (e) {
       //some code here for selecting the text.
   });
```

and also for deselecting the selected text i have written the mousedown event for deselecting text like

```
    editor.mousedown(function (e) {
      //deselect text code
    });
```

the issue here i am facing is like i am not able to get the selection as mouse down event is also fired when i double click and selection goes out.

Comment: you mean your code is not working only in mousedown right ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be work

```
var editor = $("#TargetContent");
editor.on({
  mousedown: function() {
    // do something
  },
  dblclick: function() {
    // do something
  }
});
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2w05dqp8/)

Comment: Sorry bro this didnt worked for me..i am having some different scenario.:)
I got some another alternative for solving this problem.

Comment: its better to make live example so we can figure it out please make fiddle if you can